# Check if string contains only combinations of array elements (numbers and words)

Tags: php

I've searched for hours and can't find any example of what I'm trying to do. I can't even figure out what php function needs to be used, but I'm thinking probably a regex. I attempted to use in_array and it didn't work. I don't know enough about regexes to even set up a test. Here's the problem... Say my array is:

```
$sizeopts = array('0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '.5',
 ' Wide', ' Narrow', 'XS', 'Small', 'Medium', 'Large', 'XL');
```

The textbox name is "size", and I want to only allow combinations of the above to be submitted. Example valid input: "10.5 Wide" or "3XL". Invalid input: "1X" or "2Wide" (missing the space in front of Wide). I have several different size arrays I need to validate. I'm not just using drop-downs because there are two many different possible combinations. Thanks for any help you can offer!

Comment: So `1MediumLarge Narrow0.5.5.5` would be ok?

Comment: They wouldn't make sense, but yes, they could be submitted. :) I realize this is in no way fool-proof, but it's the best solution I could come up with. I show all the valid options to the user and they're even clickable (automatically inserts them into the textbox). I'm just trying to minimize the amount of different sizes that get entered into the db... have a bit of standardization. Example: I don't want some entering "XXL" and others "2XL", so I eliminate (hopefully) the possibility of entering "XXL".

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$valid = preg_match("/[0-9]+(?:\.5)?(?: Wide| Narrow|XS|Small|Medium|Large|XL)/",$input);
```

Comment: since the OP likely cannot decipher/understand that you could use `PCRE_EXTENDED` modifier and add inline docs to that for clarity. Readable Regex ftw.

Comment: Thanks very much Kolink! This works, and I'll accept the answer. But is it not possible to check against my existing arrays, avoiding having to write regex statements (if that's the proper thing to call them) for each?

Comment: Actually, after testing more, this isn't quite the solution. It doesn't allow just "Small" or just "Medium", etc. to be entered. It's good that it doesn't allow just " Wide" or just " Narrow", as those should have numbers in front of them, but the other words should be able to be used on their own.

Comment: It also needs to accept numbers on their own. I can figure out how to do what I want only by using 3 separate preg_matches. If anyone could help me combine it into one, that would be awesome, but I haven't been getting a whole lot of feedback on this site and really don't care for the setup here, so I think it's time to find a new site for coding help.